# Visual Studio 2015 D4024 & LNK1181

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I just installed the Community version of VS2015 and I can't even build a Hello World template. I read a few LNK1181 solution on StackOverflow and visited few forums but no solution seemed to work.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

D4024:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning   D4024   unrecognized source file type ' ■/', object file
>   assumed   HelloWorld  D:\Projects\VisualStudio\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\CL   1

LNK1181:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error LNK1181 cannot open input file
>   'ÿþ/.obj' HelloWorld  D:\Projects\VisualStudio\HelloWorld\HelloWorld\LINK 1

Comment: Do you use any special (not ascii) character for the filenames or path where the files are stored?

Comment: No, that's why I so confused. This is the path where you can find the sln in "D:\Projects\VisualStudio\HelloWorld". I copied the path from the explorer.

Comment: try to remove `ÿþ/.obj` in debug folder and build again. this file name contained **not ascii** character

Comment: The Debug folder in the root is empty and the Debug folder in HelloWorld (where you can find vcxproj file) only has tlog file and tlog folder. I also tried to repair VS but the only message I get is that Redistributable is already installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial solution to my problem is to replace the cl.exe, c1.dll and c2.dll in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 for the updated version that can be found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin. This does make it possible for me to compile but not to debug.